# Search with Sphinx

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

I have 2 tables:

```
book (
    id, name, category_id
);

category (
    id, name
);
```

Can I use `sql_joined_field` for full-text search by `Sphinx`, if i need to search it from category index?
I think some thing like that :

```
     sql_query = Select * from category
     sql_joined_field = book_names from query;\
                       select book.name, category.id as category_id \
                       from book join category on category.id = book.category_id \
                       order by category_id
```

Or I must to use GROUP_CONCAT for that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add new index `books` with `category_id` and `name`. And for filtration categories by book names I search through `books` for category_id and then filter categories by ids...

Answer (score 0):

Your `sql_joined_field` is not quite right, but you have the right idea.

```
sql_query = select id, name from book
sql_joined_field = category_names from query;\
                   select book.id, category.name \
                   from book join category on category.id = book.category_id \
                   order by book_id
```

The query needs to select the document_id, and the column to add to the index.

Your document_id should be the book.id

---

Edit, actully because there can only be one category per book, dont need to use use joined fieled at all!

```
sql_query = select book.id, book.name, category.name as category \
                   from book left join category on category.id = book.category_id
```

Comment: I mean, that i must sort category index by books